# Finding a dynamic intersection of a table

Tags: sql, join, intersect

I have a query that will return some results like

```
London      111
London      222
London      333
Manchester  333
Liverpool   111
Liverpool   222
Liverpool   333
Leeds       111
Leeds       222
Leeds       333
```

My stored procedure takes in a user defined table that is a list of codes like
111 and 222, but it could take in any number of codes depending on user input from a website

Given that 111 and 333 are passed in I want the SP to return London, Liverpool and Leeds (not manchester) because

They all have records with **both** these codes

Any clues on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. What have tried & researched?--see the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two tables like this:

```
CREATE table towns (town varchar(16), code int);
insert into towns values 
   ('London', 111),('London', 222),
   ('London', 333),('Manchester', 333),
   ('Liverpool', 111),('Liverpool', 222),
   ('Liverpool', 333),('Leeds', 111),
   ('Leeds' ,222),('Leeds',333);

create table codes (ccde int);
insert into codes values (111),(333);
```

You should try

```
SELECT town, code FROM towns INNER JOIN codes on ccde=code GROUP BY town
HAVING COUNT(*)=(select count(*) from codes)
```

Please check out this edited version. My first try was obviously wrong.

You can find a demo here: http://rextester.com/DCWD90908

**Edit**

Just noticed that my command would give wrong results if there isn't a `unique` restriction on the columns `town, code` in `towns`. In case there can be double records in `towns`, like `'Manchester', 333` appearing twice, then the following will still deliver the right results:

```
SELECT town FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM towns) t 
INNER JOIN codes ON ccde=code GROUP BY town
HAVING COUNT(*)=(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM codes)
```

http://rextester.com/RZJK41394

Answer (score 0):

Throw the query results into a temporary table and re-query it like this.

You can do a basic `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT name , code 
FROM [table] AS t1 
INNER JOIN [table] AS t2 
 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.code = '111' AND t2.code = '333'
```

This will get inefficient for larger data sets though.

Another method would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and a `sub-SELECT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ( 
    SELECT name , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY code) AS row_count
    FROM [table] AS t1 
    WHERE t1.code IN ('333' , '111')
    GROUP BY t1.name, t1.code ) AS list
WHERE list.row_count > 1
```